# MacOS 10.14 Plotly dash python script not running on localhost

Tags: python, macos, localhost, plotly-dash

I am trying to run a python Plotly dash script through terminal. The code is correct, since it was working the last time and it is not using a file from local computer. 
Usually when running a Plotly dash code, I would have gotten an address which was the localhost http://127.0.0.1:8050/ and the code would work fine. Now, after two months that I have not used a Plotly dash code, I cannot run any and I keep getting the same error:

```
Running on http://x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0:8050/
Debugger PIN: 818-411-787
 * Serving Flask app "dashfile" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dashfile.py", line 390, in <module>
    app.run_server(debug=True)
  File "/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1509, in run_server
    self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
  File "/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1030, in run_simple
    s.bind(server_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

So my localhost is fine and I can ping localhost easily. The problem is that I want the dash code to be run on my localhost. Not some strange address http://x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0:8050/. 
At the end of the dash script there is a part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I have tried to tell the python script in here to run on localhost but it did not work.
Any ideas what I can try next?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue at the dash hello world https://dash.plotly.com/layout. I'm using conda on macOS 10.13.6

Comment: app.run_server(debug=True,host = '127.0.0.1') was a workaround for me

Comment: @BenoîtFayolle Yep, it worked for me as well. app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port=8050, debug=True)
Do you want to post it as an answer and I accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app.run_server(debug=True,host = '127.0.0.1') is a workaround

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port=8050, debug=True). 
Trying to address to local host inside python script.